In IntelliJ with JUnit5 I can command click on the argument to @MethodSource to jump to the method. How / where is this implemented?
For example, if I have:
static Stream<String> arguments() {
    return Stream.of("one", "two");
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("arguments")
void method(String argument) {}

I'm able to command click "arguments" and IntelliJ will navigate me to the actual method arguments. How and where is this functionality implemented? I'm working on a project where this sort of feature would be quite nice to recreate.
I thought this might've been implemented in IntelliJ's JUnit plugin but I'm unable to find the source code for this.

What do you mean you can't find the source code? IntelliJ CE is open source - https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community

If I understand correctly, this is the relevant file. Is that what you are looking for?

Yes, that's it, thank you! I should've researched more carefully before posting :)
